# replacement for c-loop if the array may be nil for swift 2.2 and above

Tags: swift

So C-loop was deprecated in swift 2.2 and will be removed in swift 3. I'm against it but have to live with it.

I had a function like below:

```
func levelOrder(root: TreeNode?) -> [[Int]] {
    guard root != nil else { return [] }

    let leftArr = levelOrder(root!.left)
    let rightArr = levelOrder(root!.right)
    var merged = [[Int]]()
    merged.append([root!.val])
    for i in 0...max(leftArr.count, rightArr.count)
    {
        var current = [Int]()
        let currentLeft: [Int]? = i < leftArr.count ? leftArr[i] : nil
        let currentRight: [Int]? = i < rightArr.count ? rightArr[i] : nil
        for var j = 0; j < currentLeft?.count; j++
        {
            current.append(currentLeft![j])
        }
        for var j = 0; j < currentRight?.count; j++
        {
            current.append(currentRight![j])
        }
        if current.count > 0
        {
            merged.append(current)
        }
    }
    return merged
}
```

So for the inner for loop, I am using c style loop, it is perfect that if `currentLeft` is nil, the for loop will never get executed at all, so the code is clean and elegant.

Now the question is, in order to use swift loops, I have to use a if condition to check if the array is nil, which is annoying. Is there any good solution to replace the c loop without introducing more if condition like mine?

Comment: While Sulthan's answer should improve your code, a direct answer would be: `currentLeft?.forEach { current.append($0) }`. If it's `nil`, nothing happens.

Comment: @Eendje seems you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your use case, the simplest solution is using an empty array instead of `nil`.

```
let currentLeft: [Int] = i < leftArr.count ? leftArr[i] : []
let currentRight: [Int] = i < rightArr.count ? rightArr[i] : []
```

Also, you might use a more functional approach:

```
currentLeft.forEach {
   current.append($0)
}
```

or just:

```
let current = currentLeft + currentRight
```

Comment: oh yeah, I think about use []. But it will not be always possible, if it is nil, any idea?

Comment: use currentLeft?.forEach {
   current.append($0)
} seems good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simplify and shorten, because you don't need your own inner loops:

```
for i in 0...max(leftArr.count, rightArr.count)
{
    var current = [Int]()

    if i < leftArr.count {
        current.appendContentsOf(leftArr[i])
    }
    if i < rightArr.count {
        current.appendContentsOf(rightArr[i])
    }

    if current.count > 0
    {
        merged.append(current)
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I am just practicing some tree algorithms, so writing in a C style in swift. I like your idea! Thanks!